# Plugin integrating SMS api with WooCommerce

Tags: php, api, woocommerce, plugins, sms

I am trying to build a simple plugin to link my WooCommerce store with the Unifonic SMS service

Unifonic team has sent to me this guide

> https://unifonic.docs.apiary.io/#reference/messages/send/send

The code I use, unfortunately without the desired result

```php
 * Plugin Name: my sms
 * Plugin URI: https://000000000000
 * Description: sms
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: sms
 * Author URI: sms
 */


add_action('woocommerce_order_status_cancelled', 'custom_sms_order', 10, 1);
function custom_sms_order($order_id) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $customer_id = $order->user_id; 
    $billing_phone = get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_phone', true );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.unifonic.com/rest/Messages/Send");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, AppSid=00000000000000t=".$billing_phone."&Body=test test test);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    var_dump($response);

    return $order_id;
}
```

Comment: i think you should put your key here instead of zeros AppSid=00000000000000

Comment: Yes I know that I deleted my key so I can publish the code

Comment: What error you get?

Comment: Word Press does not accept activation the plugin

Comment: show us the error in your question, add more info

Comment: When I click on activate the plugin the page reloaded without activating the plugin